# Why does it say "Bad Login" when I try to connect to this server with one account but not the other?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every time I try to log into one particular server with my main account it says `Bad Login`, but I can log in fine using my other Minecraft account.

I also tried logging into that server from another computer, but it also says `Bad Login`!

Why is just one account getting a `Bad Login` from this one server?

Comment: did you pay for your MC account?

Comment: @ratchetfreak She (or he) did pay, I just checked it.

Comment: LMAO i have 2 accounts

Comment: Can you log in to `minecraft.net`?

Comment: Yeah i can just not log into servers..which is bull on all levels possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get a "Bad Login" error from a specific server if that server can't reach `minecraft.net` to verify your account.

This means that if the *server* has a hard time connecting to `minecraft.net` (either because `minecraft.net` has just gone down, or because the server has an unreliable network route to `minecraft.net`) even if you have no problem connecting to `minecraft.net` to login to your account initially, then you will get intermittent "Bad Login" errors from the server that's having network problems.

Comment: We've closed this question as duplicate while cleaning up old Minecraft questions. You might want to repost this answer on the original question

Comment: @PrivatePansy Thanks! I've done so now. Aside, is there any reason duplicates like this aren't just having their answers merged?

Comment: I think it's not done automatically because it is assumed that the answers are likely to be duplicates too, which they are most of the time. I noticed it's not in this case, which is why I dropped the comment

Comment: @PrivatePansy Oh yes, that makes sense. Then thank you; I appreciate the effort to both notice and tie up that loose end. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `bad login` error can be caused by a number of things.

- Playing the game with the Java browser applet (http://minecraft.net/play)
- Not using a paid account, which can be verified through `https://minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=[Your username]`
- Playing the game in a client that improperly authenticates with minecraft's login servers.

Comment: We've closed this question as duplicate while cleaning up old Minecraft questions. You might want to repost this answer on the original question